# using external terminal vscode windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with C, when i run,i wanna instead of using the integrated terminal in vscode, use an external terminal(cmd), i configurated my launch.json with `"externalConsole": true`, and in my settings.json, I use `{"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",}`, but nothing happen.

launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "name": "(gdb) Iniciar",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\main.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Habilitar a reformatação automática para gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description":  "Definir Tipo de Desmontagem como Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

settings.json:

```
{"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",}
```